# How to start Microsoft Word from Java FX with parameters to run a macro

Tags: ms-word, javafx-8

I have a document management system which stores files in a MS Word format.  In my application, I would like to be able to open that document in Word.

I would like Word to handle all of the file system access out of the content management system.  What I need to do is the following:

1) Create a new document based off a template, and then provide information that can be parsed and placed into specific fields.

I see I can do this as follows:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Office/Office15/winword.exe /ttemplate_name");
```

My assumption here is that the template is installed on the local drive.  However I would like to provide some data so that fields could be prepopulated and I am not sure how to do that?

2) I would like to be able to run a macro to open the document directly from the content management system.  I think I can run a macro as follows:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Office/Office15/winword.exe /mmacro_name");
```

However, in this case, I would need to provide the document id from the content management system so that it can retrieve it and open it.

I am unsure what switch or parameter I can use to provide the additional data for word?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Word provides no command-line facility to pass arguments or data when opening or creating a document.

As long as macro code is available, the macro can *read* data that's stored somewhere, such as in an XML file. But the file path would need to be hard-coded or derivable from a known location (path).

You don't necessarily need to call a macro in a document (or template attached to the document). If the macro is named AutoNew or AutoOpen it will execute automatically when a document is created from the template or, respectively, when a document is opened.

Comment: Is there a way to connect to a running instance from word and pass parameters over to it?